# SFTP web portal for clients

Tags: ftp, sftp, web

We need a web managed space where we can upload specific files to client folders and they can upload files back via some sort of web portal. We would give them credentials and then they could login and see only what they are allowed to see. Basically regular FTP with a layer on top so clients don't need to use filezilla or something.

Comment: FTP or SFTP? Or just portal to store files, folders and access to them?

Comment: @Jakuje SFTP. And, both. Need to give clients a login to our SFTP Portal where they can retrieve and upload files.

Comment: @Narzard SFTP is not at all “regular FTP”. Please edit your title and Question to describe *precisely* your needs.